# How to create a login form with text fields,getters and setters with following code?

Tags: android, html, android-activity

and  i am a new to android i don't have any knowledge about it and i have to develop an android login application in which i have to take user name and password from one activity and have to get verified ans display a message in another activity. Since i am findin so many solutions from STACKOVERFLOW i expect this one will also get solved.i have pasted the code below, its not passing the data from first activity to second

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.widget.Toast;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Serializable
  {
private EditText  username=null;
private EditText  password=null;
private Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
public MainActivity(){}
public MainActivity(EditText username,EditText password){
this.username=username;
 this.password=password;
  }

    public EditText getUsername() 
     {
return username;
   }
       public void setUsername(EditText username) {
    this.username = username;
        }
        public EditText getPassword() {
    return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(EditText password) {
    this.password = password;
        }
           @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
              Button login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                   {

          @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
        Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Verify.class);
        in.putExtra("MainActivity",obj);
        startActivity(in);
        }
             });
                   }
                   }
```

this s my another activity

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 //import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;  
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 //import android.widget.Toast;
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Serializable
     {
    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    private Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       public MainActivity(){}
       public MainActivity(EditText username,EditText password){
        this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
       }

                 public EditText getUsername() {
         return username;
                }
                public void setUsername(EditText username) {
          this.username = username;
                  }

             public EditText getPassword() {
          return password;
               }

          public void setPassword(EditText password) {
      this.password = password;
          }

            @Override
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
               login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
               Button login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
              login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
              {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
        Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Verify.class);
        in.putExtra("MainActivity",obj);
        startActivity(in);
        }
                 });
             }
            }
```

this my manifest file:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.login"
            android:versionCode="1"
             android:versionName="1.0" >
         <uses-sdk
             android:minSdkVersion="8"
              android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
         <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
               <activity
               android:name="com.example.login.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
              <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
        android:name="com.example.login.Verify"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_check" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VERIFY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.login.Take"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_take" >
        </activity>
         </application>
          </manifest>
```

i know this code s very stupid i am a non programmer but please help me.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be an only html question. you might edit and add more relevant tags

Comment: Your first activity and the second seems to be the same...

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Androids Developer Guide 
[Building your first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

In order for the next activity to query the extra data, you should define the key for your intent's extra using a public constant. So add the EXTRA_MESSAGE definition to the top of the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_VALUE = "com.example.myfirstapp.VALUE";
    ...
}
```

/** Called when the user clicks */

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VerifyActivity.class);
    String value= *YOUR VALUE*;
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUE, value);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Put this in your second activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value= intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_VALUE);
```

}

Now the variable value contains your value